# Unable to get results after executing saved search from rest API

Tags: splunk

I am trying to get the results of a splunk saved search(report) via REST API But getting error as " Error in 'savedsearch' command: Unable to find saved search named 'test'."

curl -s -k -u 'usr:pwd' "https://host:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export" -d search=" savedsearch test"

Saved search is owned by me.Can anybody please advise what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you're using /servicesNS/* (Namespace) endpoint, which forces the user and app context.
In your case, it's looking for a savedsearch owned by "admin" user and created in the "search" app.

If you created the saved search (report) in the "search" app and it is only owned by you (usr) then use this instead :

```
curl -s -k -u 'usr:pwd' "https://host:8089/servicesNS/usr/search/search/jobs/export" -d search=" savedsearch test"
```

Read this documentation: [Splunk Rest API Basic concepts | Namespace](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTUM/RESTusing#Namespace)